# How to use printf without storing data into a variable nasm?

Tags: windows, assembly, x86, nasm

I am trying to print a string in assembly without having to store my data into a variable.

**What works**:

```
global  _main
    extern  _printf

section .data:
    message: db  'AAAA'

section .text
    _main:
    push    message
    call    _printf
    add     esp, 4
    ret
```

**Now, what I want is to push `AAAA` directly to stack and call `printf` to print it without having to store it in `message`.**

I spent good few hours with different methods trying to do it myself, but so far failed.

Tried:

Method #1:

```
push 41414141h
call _printf
```

Method #2:

```
mov esi, 41414141h
push esi
call _printf
```

Method #3:

```
mov   esi, 41414141h
mov   edi, 7325      ; '%s'
call  _printf
; or storing 'AAAA' in EDI and storing '%s' in ESI
```

Method #4:

```
mov   esi, 41414141h
mov   edi, 7325      ; '%s'
push  esi
push  edi
call  _printf
; or storing 'AAAA' in EDI and storing '%s' in ESI
```

Method #5:

```
mov   esi, 41414141h
mov   edi, 7325      ; '%s'
push  esi
xor   eax, eax
push  eax            ; just push a null byte to the stack
push  edi
call  _printf
; or storing 'AAAA' in EDI and storing '%s' in ESI
```

and many more that I don't even remember.

So, what is the proper way of printing a value stored in a register.

and if possible to answer below too, I would really appreciate it.

After investigating a bit on how does the first attempt works. I realized that, the the data or `AAAA` is stored in program's stack and then the address of the data is pushed to ESP.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIBbQ.png)

Unfortunately, I don't how to push data to program's stack\ `.data` section or if that is even possible and how to push the address of that section to ESP.

Comment: `push 0; push 41414141h; push esp; call _printf` Note you need to zero terminate the string. You will also need to remove things you put on the stack.

Comment: @Jester, you are just better, well that worked :)

Comment: your data-section version only works because there happens to be some `0` padding after it.  You should be using `db 'AAAA', 0` to make a C-string, or use `fwrite` with a pointer,length so you don't need a terminator.  (Also, normally you'd put read-only constant data in `section .rodata`)

Answer (score -1):

I'm not used to using the `_printf` function, but I can show how you can do this with the syscall:

```
mov dword [esp-4], 'AAAA' ; This is the red-zone, try googling it
    
; The actual printing
mov eax, 4
mov ebx, 1
lea ecx, [esp-4]
mov edx, 4
int 80h
```

(This uses the Linux 32-bit syscalls by the way, not sure what the windows syscalls are)

Maybe try `push`ing `[esp-4]`?

[EDIT] Forgot to mention a major limitation of this (At least with the syscall, still not sure about _printf) that this can only print a max of 4 characters, no more.
[ANOTHER EDIT] As other commenters have pointed out, this method is possibly unsafe (check comments), so you may decide to avoid it.

Comment: Note that it's technically unsafe to rely on data below ESP staying unmodified between your mov store and when the system call reads it.  A signal handler (or a debugger evaluating a `print foo()`) can use that stack space.  Only the x86-64 System V ABI guarantees a red-zone below RSP that's safe to use.  In this case, `push 'AAAA'` / `mov ecx, esp` would be a better option.

Comment: re: your actual answer to the question: `mov dword [esp-4], 'AAAA'` / `push [esp-4]` would *not* be a good idea.  That would be equivalent to `push 'AAAA'`; `push [esp-4]` is basically a NOP (loads and re-stores a dword from the same location: load from below the old ESP, then store at the new ESP after decrementing).  libc printf expects a *pointer* to a 0-terminated C-string (implicit length, that's why there's no `4` arg), not the value.  The Windows cdecl calling convention more or less matches the Linux i386 Sys V calling convention for this so you can play with `call printf` on Linux.

Comment: Anyway, as mentioned in comments on the question, you can push a terminating `0` and *then* push some string data.  ESP then points to the C-string, so you can `push esp` / `call printf`.  And BTW, unlike Linux, Windows' raw system call interface is not documented or supported, so the standard way is to use WinAPI DLL function calls.  (Or reverse-engineer the DLLs to make raw system calls directly on a specific version of Windows.)  32-bit Windows DLLs I think end up making a far call or jump into 64-bit user-space to use `syscall`, which seems like a lot of overhead vs. Linux `sysenter`.

Comment: I'd recommend fixing your answer to show something that can construct a 0-terminated C-string on the stack.  I downvoted because this doesn't show anything useful for calling printf. Linux `sys_write` isn't particularly useful as an answer to a Windows question, and there are Linux Q&As that already show that.  I'd be happy to remove or reverse my downvote if/when this answer improves, especially fixing the suggestion that `push [esp-4]` might somehow be useful.  If you meant LEA / push, then keep in mind that push will overwrite whatever's at `[esp-4]` because it does ESP-=4 and [esp]=src.